# error with Timer class

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript, timer

This is the error i'm receiving.  I just transferred all my codes into classes.  It becomes very complex between timeline and classes.  I have a MovieClip with the linkage property named "PopUpItem" and everytime the class is activated, an Item appears on the screen for 3 seconds, then moves towards the inventory.  I had it working before when it was on the timeline, but not anymore.  Any suggestions?

[SWF] VQuest%20V2.swf - 2955884 bytes after decompression
    undefined
    at flash.utils::Timer()
    at PopUpItem()[PopUpItem::PopUpItem:2]

```
package {
import flash.utils.Timer;
import flash.display.MovieClip;
import flash.events.MouseEvent;
import flash.events.TimerEvent;
import flash.events.Event;

public class PopUpItem extends MovieClip {
    var popUpTimer: Timer = new Timer(1000, 3); // 3 seconds
    var popUpItem: MovieClip = new PopUpItem;
    var i = 0;

public function popUpFunction() {
        popUpTimer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER_COMPLETE, onComplete);
    }

public function itemReceived(received) {
        for (i = 0; i < 1; i++) {
            addChild(popUpItem);
            popUpItem.popUpAnimation.gotoAndStop(received);
            popUpItem.x = 400;
            popUpItem.y = 250;
            popUpItem.itemText.text = "You got a " + received + "."
            popUpTimer.start();
            popUpItem.play();
        }
    }

public function onComplete(event: TimerEvent): void {
        removeChild(popUpItem);
        i = 0;
    }

}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The first problem I can see is creating an instance of the PopUpItem Class in the constructor function of the PopUpItem Class - this will most probably cause a stack overflow error.
If the PopUpItem Class is your main 'document' Class, you only need to link to it (from Flash) in the properties panel.
If you want the PopUpItem Class instantiated inside another Class, store the instance in a variable in that OTHER Class - don't try to store a PopUpItem instance in a variable IN the PopUpItem constructor.

Comment: Yeah, it used to be on the MainTimeline.  I replaced that entire variable with "this"  so at least the game plays now without that error.  Thanks a lot.